# Android: What's the best way to extend both the ActionBarActivity and BaseAdapter?

Tags: android

I was wondering - what is the best way to extend both the ActionBarActivity and the BaseAdapter? I know that Java doesn't allow for multiple inheritance, but I need both of these to be available to get my application to work correctly.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to extend both Activity and Adapter.

Comment: Why do you want BaseAdapter to extended in ActionBarActivity class when you can create separate custom adapter object using different class ?

Comment: You're putting too much stuff on a single class. Create an Adapter instance.

Comment: I'm trying to use the BaseAdapter for a listView but I need the ActionBarActivity to display options to the user. 
How would I go about creating an Adapter Instance?

Comment: The answer is that you cannot do that, and also you don't need to.  You may need to re-factor your code a bit. Just create another class that extends `BaseAdapter`, and go from there.

Comment: Well you can't do this how you think you might be able to. An Activity and an Adapter are totally different things... But there is a way to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new class which extends from BaseAdapter.
Then in your List etc. set your Adapter with:

`mListView.setAdapter(mBaseAdapter);`

This sums it up: [Android Adapter Good Practices](http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/)

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering - what is the best way to extend both the ActionBarActivity and the BaseAdapter?

There isn't a "best" way to do what you're asking.

> I know that Java doesn't allow for multiple inheritance

Correct and, based on what you seem to think is a good approach, this is a prime example of why multiple inheritance is not necessarily a good thing. In languages which do allow for multiple inheritance, it is all too easy to simply "bolt together" disjointed classes which have no direct relationship with respect to their functionality.

Think carefully about what various classes do and why they do it.

What exactly is an Android `Activity`? Well, in general terms, it is a UI framework - something with intelligence designed to present the user interface to the end-user and to allow interaction in various ways.

What exactly is an Android `Adapter`? Again in general terms, it is a mechanism which acts as an intermediary between a dataset and an `AdapterView`.

Whilst an `Activity` might present 'views' to the user, it is not an actual 'view' in its own right and, as such, doesn't directly need any specific 'view' type capabilities nor the capabilities of other ancillary components such as an `Adapter` - not directly at least. In reality, from what you describe your `Activity` would need to extend `ActionBarActivity`, `Adapter` AND `AdapterView`. At that point however, (if it were possible) you'll have locked it down to a point it will be difficult to reuse for any other purpose - either that or you'd have a heck of a lot of code to make it multi-purpose.

> but I need both of these to be available to get my application to work correctly.

Sure, but an `Activity` often needs a `Button` or an `ImageView` or a `ViewPager` etc etc - that doesn't mean, however, the `Activity` needs to extend any of those classes directly.

As has been said in the comments on your question, create your own custom adapter which extends `BaseAdapter`, create your own activity which extends `ActionBarActivity` and then use them as you would any other `Activity` or `Adapter` class.